# "Cross-multiplying" isomorphic quotient groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

The form of the second isomorphism theorem that I learned (for $G$ a group with $S$ a subgroup and $N$ a normal subgroup) is:
$$SN \  / \   N \cong S \ / \ (S \cap N)$$
I'm seeing it used in a proof, however, as:
$$SN \  / \   S \cong N \ / \ (S \cap N)$$
i.e. it looks as if the quotient groups in the equation are being cross-multiplied as if it were $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$.

Is this some general property of groups or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The only question is which group is normal. You could change the names to anything you want; for that matter, if Peter and Daniel are subgroups of $G$, and Daniel is normal in $G$, then $(\mathrm{Peter})(\mathrm{Daniel})/\mathrm{Daniel} \cong \mathrm{Peter}/(\mathrm{Daniel}\cap\mathrm{Peter})$. If $S$ is normal, you are just applying the exact same theorem; if $S$ is not normal, then the second expression is incoherent, since $S$ need not be normal in $SN$ nor $S\cap N$ in $N$. If $S$ is normal in $SN$, though, then you can just apply the theorem.

Comment: Oh I see, in the proof I'm looking at they're both normal, that makes sense thank you